# download the single file from s3 location using java

Tags: java, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I have an amazon s3 bucket which contains one file and I am looking for a way to download that one file using the file extension. currently, I have the code to download multiple files from s3 bucket using key and then filter based on the extension. Something like this:

```
s3.listObjects(operaBucketName, keyName)
          .getObjectSummaries()
          .forEach(s -> keys.add(s.getKey()));
List<String> filteredKeys =
        keys.stream().filter(s -> s.contains(extension)).collect(Collectors.toList());
//add to file list
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String key : filteredKeys) {
      File file = new File(FilenameUtils.getFullPath(localDirectory) + FilenameUtils.getName(key));
      downloadFileFromS3(operaBucketName, key, file);
      files.add(file);
    }
```

I want to do this but targeting a single file. I tried `s3.getObject(operaBucketName, keyName);`, but the com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3Object doesn't have a way to check the file extension. I think using this [How to write an S3 object to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7679924/how-to-write-an-s3-object-to-a-file) I can write S3object contents to file.
Also, just in case, there are multiple files in the given s3 folder(key), will getObject throw an exception?

Sdk version used:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
      <version>1.11.792</version>
    </dependency>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AWS provides a bom and show how you can include it [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java#importing-the-bom) shortly below.

Importing the BOM

```xml
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
      <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.411</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Using the SDK Maven modules

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-ec2</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-s3</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

On [aws java sdk documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/setup-project-maven.html) you can find how to create project template too.

```bash
mvn -B archetype:generate \
 -DarchetypeGroupId=software.amazon.awssdk \
 -DarchetypeArtifactId=archetype-lambda -Dservice=s3 -Dregion=US_WEST_2 \
 -DgroupId=com.example.myapp \
 -DartifactId=myapp
```

How to get a single file from s3 [more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#download-object) and [full example](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/S3ObjectOperations.java)

```java
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = GetObjectRequest.builder()
    .bucket(bucketName)
    .key(key)
    .build();

s3.getObject(getObjectRequest);
```

One important note about file extension

> An Amazon S3 bucket has no directory hierarchy such as you would find
> in a typical computer file system. You can, however, create a logical
> hierarchy by using object key names that imply a folder structure. For
> example, instead of naming an object sample.jpg, you can name it
> photos/2006/February/sample.jpg.

> To get an object from such a logical hierarchy, specify the full key
> name for the object in the GET operation. For a virtual hosted-style
> request example, if you have the object
> photos/2006/February/sample.jpg, specify the resource as
> /photos/2006/February/sample.jpg. For a path-style request example, if
> you have the object photos/2006/February/sample.jpg in the bucket
> named examplebucket, specify the resource as
> /examplebucket/photos/2006/February/sample.jpg. For more information
> about request types, see HTTP Host Header Bucket Specification.

There is no **folder**/directory in s3 so you will not get any multi file exception.

And AWS suggesting to use file **extension** in the object name, this way you can get the object/file and no need to check extension. [javadoc](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#getObject(software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest))

To determine the type of object or file, you can verify its content-type. [How to get the content type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65970335/175554) and with apache tika [find the extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542266/175554). This is more resource consuming and slow way therefore I suggest using the extensions in the object name.